# Apache2 Logging Conditional with multiple env set

Tags: logging, configuration, apache2

So we have X-Forwarded-For enabled on our SLBs which is working, and I've got correct logging working via the [link here](http://www.techstacks.com/howto/log-client-ip-and-xforwardedfor-ip-in-apache.html), which says to use this SetEnvIF statement.

The problem we are running into is, the SLBs also check ever 5seconds via a GET /health.html file, which is filling up our logs. I was able to find a way to get apache2 to stop logging specific files, however I cannot seem to find a way to do both X-Forward-For and Don't Log specific files.

This was my last attempt, when I read a blog saying you could use multiple Env and sepearate them by a ',' which didn't owrk :(.

```
    #logs
    LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
    LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" proxy
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^.*\..*\..*\..*" forwarded
    SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/health\.html$" dontlog

    CustomLog "/www/logs/access.log"  combined env=!forwarded,!dontlog
    CustomLog "/www/logs/access.log"  proxy env=forwarded
```

I appreciate everyones help.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I was able to get it working "sort of" by removing the comine LogFormat line and the !forward,!dontlog CustomLog line since my thought is they will not be used as the application flow is through the SLB. I changed the only Custom Log line to have proxy env=!dontlog which will Format the log with the expected X-Forwarded-For while not logging the health.html checks. I've not tested a direct HTTP connection to each server..bypassing SLB to see if it logs correctly.

Answer (score 3):

For your case it should be:

```
CustomLog       /www/logs/access.log combined expr=(reqenv('forwarded')=='no'&&reqenv('dontlog')=='no')
CustomLog       /www/logs/access.log proxy expr=(reqenv('forwarded')=='yes')
```

The last one can be an `env` but I left as a `expr` for a `'yes'` example.

Comment: This answer got me going in the right direction, but found I had to explicitly set forwarded=yes and test for a 'no' with a !='yes'. It seemed an unset env var did not actually equate to =='no'

Answer (score -2):

Syntax:

```
CustomLog file|pipe format|nickname [env=[!]environment-variable| expr=expression]
```